# Data Bars through stylesheet transform?

Tags: xslt

i have some data in XML format. For **example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TableSizes>
   <Table name="AuditLog" rows="13193925" reserved="4896864" data="2522592" indexSize="2373824" unused="448"/>
   <Table name="Customers" rows="7021839" reserved="3243392" data="1480640" indexSize="1762640" unused="112"/>
</TableSizes>
```

i would like that data to be transformed and displayed by the client. So when i feed the User Agent the xml, i supply it a stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='databaseSize.xslt' media='all'?>
<TableSizes>
   <Table name="AuditLog" rows="13193925" reserved="4896864" data="2522592" indexSize="2373824" unused="448"/>
   <Table name="Customers" rows="7021839" reserved="3243392" data="1480640" indexSize="1762640" unused="112"/>
</TableSizes>
```

This causes it to be transformed into some suitable HTML. And that works well enough.

But now i want to add **Data Bars**:

As it is now, i've been generating the HTML on the server (i.e. the server is deciding how to *display* content, rather than a stylesheet):

[image]

Which requires each table cell to have a custom `background` style applied, with the computed gradient stops:

```
<TR>
    <TD>AuditLog
    <TD style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #658FC6 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">1319,,3925
    <TD style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">489,,6864
    <TD>252,,2592
    <TD>237,,3824
    <TD>448
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD>Customers
    <TD style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #658FC6 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 51%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">702,,1839
    <TD style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 62%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">324,,3392
    <TD>148,,0640
    <TD>176,,2640
    <TD>112
</TR>
```

Obviously i'd rather have all of this performed in the client by a stylesheet, rather than doing it on the server.

Possible?

**Note**: If it's not: it's not a problem; just say so.

## What XSLT  do i have so far?

Essentially, none. The XST i have so far does nothing to add data bars:

```
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@rows"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@reserved"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@data"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@indexSize"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@unused"/>
```

i have add a dummy amount of gradient drawing code:

```
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
<TD style='background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 50%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)'><xsl:value-of select="@rows"/>
<TD style='background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 50%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)'><xsl:value-of select="@reserved"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@data"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@indexSize"/>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="@unused"/>
```

Strictly speaking, i don't even have that XSLT. i didn't want to write an entire XSLT when it cannot accomplish what i want. The XSLT i have above i created on-the-fly when someone suggested that the question isn't work answering until i at least pretend to have some XSLT first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the calculations pretty easily in XSLT and put that into a style attribute.

I created a template for each `AuditLog` and `Customers`. And then in the `Customers` template I just defined a variable for the previous values in `AuditLog` to use in the calculation. From there I used each to figure out the percent needed for the gradient(along with some quick 'rounding').

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(((@rows div $PrevRow) * 100),1,2)"/>
```

So when you take your XML and transform it with this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Table[@name='AuditLog']">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </td>
      <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">
        <xsl:value-of select="@rows"/>
      </td>
      <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">
        <xsl:value-of select="@reserved"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@data"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@indexSize"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@unused"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Table[@name='Customers']">
    <xsl:variable name="PrevRow" select="preceding-sibling::Table/@rows"/>
    <xsl:variable name="PrevReserved" select="preceding-sibling::Table/@reserved"/>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:text>background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(((@rows div $PrevRow) * 100),1,2)"/>
          <xsl:text>%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@rows"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:attribute name="style">
          <xsl:text>background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(((@reserved div $PrevReserved) * 100),1,2)"/>
          <xsl:text>%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="@reserved"/>
        <br/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$PrevReserved"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@data"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@indexSize"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@unused"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You get this output:

```
<tr>
  <td>AuditLog</td>
  <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">13193925</td>
  <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">4896864</td>
  <td>2522592</td>
  <td>2373824</td>
  <td>448</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Customers</td>
  <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 53%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">7021839</td>
  <td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF595E 0%,rgb(255,255,255) 66%,rgb(255,255,255) 100%)">3243392<br/>4896864</td>
  <td>1480640</td>
  <td>1762640</td>
  <td>112</td>
</tr>
```